# Merging three audio files to one file loses a channel

Tags: ffmpeg

I have three audio files: `1.wav`, `2.wav` and `3.wav`. I'm looking to create a 3-channel file using `ffmpeg`: the channel layout doesn't actually matter as the content isn't channel-specific, but the layout `3.0` or `3.0(back)` would do.

If I do:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.wav -i 2.wav -i 3.wav -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=3[aout]" -map "[aout]" output.m4a
```

This creates a 2.1 layout file, where the 3rd channel is "LFE" and therefore muffled on normal playback:

[image]

So if I force the layout to 3.0:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.wav -i 2.wav -i 3.wav -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=3[aout]" -map "[aout]" -channel_layout 3.0 output.m4a
```

This does create a 3.0 file:

```
Output #0, ipod, to 'output.m4a':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.30.100
  Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 3.0, fltp, 197 kb/s
```

... but the 3rd channel isn't in the output file:

[image]

I've tried everything: different filters, different input and output codecs and containers, different versions of ffmpeg on different platforms: nothing seems to output the file correctly.

Comment: try: `ffmpeg -i fl.wav -i fr.wav -i fc.wav -lavfi "
[0]channelmap=FC-FL[a];
[1]channelmap=FC-FR[b];
[2]channelmap=FC-FC[c];
[a][b][c]amerge=3
" -channel_layout 3.0 out.wav`

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов: perfect, that works! I could have sworn I'd tried the `channelmap` filter before, but for whatever reason I didn't hit on the magic combination. Please post as an answer so I can credit you!